# How do I get data from grandchildren?

Tags: c#, entity-framework

I have EF 3.5 and I am trying to get information from 3 different entities.
`orders` has a navigation to `orderitems` and `orderitems` has a navigation to `ProductSize` which has navigation to `Product`.  Problem arises when I use `.Include` statement to add the additional entities to `Orders` the return only shows data from `Orders` and not from any of the others.

Here is sample

```
var query = (from c in context.Orders
.Include("OrderItems")
.Include("OrderItems.ProductSize:)
.Include("OrderItems.ProductSize.Product)

select c).ToList()

Order

OrderID
Comments
EDIPI
IssuedDate
OrderItems Navigation
ShippingLocation Navigation

OrderItem

OrderItemID
Quantity
Issued
Order Navigation
ProductSize Navigation

ProductSize

ProductSizeID
Size
NSN
Price
Items Navigation
Product Navigation
OrderItems Navigation
```

Comment: why is there a colon after ProductSize in second include?

Comment: Mistyped the Quotation marks.  They are in the actual code.

Comment: Should have read ("OrderItems.ProductSize")

Comment: And ("OrderItems.ProductSize.Product")

Comment: @MikeBartley edit your question instead of commenting the fixes

Comment: Can you please post your entity classes too?

Comment: by the way, just the 3rd include should be enough, The first 2 are not needed.

Comment: May take a few minutes it is on another device.

Comment: How do I add the images of my Entities?  New to all this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try as shown below.

```
var query = (from c in context.Orders select c)
            .Include(oi=>oi.OrderItems.Order)
            .Include(o=>o.OrderItems.ProductSize.Product)
            .ToList();
```

Comment: Thanks for the response.  Got it to work by swapping .Orders with .OrderItems.  Then did as you suggested.